# Avoid duplication using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to avoid duplication of data using jquery?
 My code is :

```
<button  id="gen">Generate</button>
<table id="report" border="1" style="visibility:hidden">
    <tr>
        <th>Sl.No.</th>
        <th>District Name</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
$("#gen").click(function(){
$("#report").css("visibility","visible");
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
  var row='<tr><td>('+(i+1)+')</td></tr>'
  $("#report").append(row);
 }
});
```

Each time when i clicking the button, the same data were shown.
How to avoid it?
sqlfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/etdx5o08/

Comment: what duplication u want to avoid?

Comment: I think this is what you are talking about - http://jsfiddle.net/etdx5o08/1/

Comment: please check your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/etdx5o08/2/

Comment: You're not duplicating any data... you are adding 5 NEW rows every time. If you don't want to do that, either don't add 5 new rows every time (only do it once), or remove all the rows before adding new ones.

Comment: @Hamza Kubba:You said actually I want. Plz give me a demo.

Comment: @jackrose several answers below already work, note though that you are creating a malformed table as you have 2 header columns but you code creates rows with only 1 column

Comment: @DelightedD0D:; The ans below doesn't satisfies my question. I just want one time adding the row( sl.no(from 1 to 5) only)).No need to increment.

Comment: @jackrose please look at the demo on my answer, does that not resolve the issue? if not please explain where it falls short and we will adjust

Comment: @jackrose try http://jsfiddle.net/etdx5o08/5/ Basically line 2 disables the button after it is clicked the first time.

Comment: @HamzaKubba Im assuming that the OP has more going on in their actual code where they actually need to be able to click the button multiple times (new data pulled from ajax or similar). Disabling the button is trivial and doesnt seem to address the issue

Comment: @DelightedD0D You might be right, I have no idea... OP didn't give many details...

Comment: @HamzaKubba that's a fair point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```js
$("#gen").click(function() {
       $("#report").parent().show();
       var rows='';
       for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         rows = rows+'<tr><td>(' + (i + 1) + ')</td><td></td></tr>'
       }
       $("#report").html(rows);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="gen">Generate</button>
    <table border="1" style="display:none">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sl.No.</th>
                <th>District Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="report"></tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: How is this any different from code above ? I think Jack is talking about duplication of Sl.No

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu It's different because it uses `.html()` which replaces all of the html in the element where as the OPs original code simply uses `.append()` to add each row to the element so when he clicks a second time, it appends the rows again under the first set duplicating the data...

Comment: @DelightedD0D: Your code works fine. But in my question , at first, table was hidden and when the button clicked it must be visible.

Comment: @jackrose Ah, sorry, I removed that when testing and forgot to put it back, edited above

Comment: @DelightedD0D: Thanks.. This is what I needed.! Thanks for spending time for me.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicates, you can simply update js as below.

```
$("#gen").click(function(){
$("#report").css("visibility","visible");
$("#report").html('<tr><th>Sl.No.</th><th>District Name</th></tr>');
for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        var row='<tr><td>('+(i+1)+')</td></tr>'
        $("#report").append(row);
    }
});
```

Just adding the below line before loop starts.

```
$("#report").html('<tr><th>Sl.No.</th><th>District Name</th></tr>');
```

Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prem_nagalla1/04q7qb23/).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This will add `<tr><th>Sl.No.</th><th>District Name</th></tr>` every time the button is clicked.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu no it wont, it will replace the element's html with `<tr><th>Sl.No.</th><th>District Name</th></tr>` every time the button is clicked, which solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#gen").click(function(){
    $("#report").css("visibility","visible");
    var table = $("#report tbody tr");
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        var row='<tr><td>('+(table.length+1+i)+')</td></tr>'
        $("#report").append(row);
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6epre5ra/)**